# Find the Region for Change of Variables in a Double Integral Problem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

Let $D$ be the region surrounded by the quadrilateral with vertices $O(0,0) , A(2,1), B(s,t)$ and $C(1,3)$ with $s$ and $t$ constants.

1- Using the change of variables $(x,y)=(au+bc+cuv, du +ev+fuv)$ Find the constants $a, b, c, d$ such as $E:0\le u \le 1 ; 0\le v\le 1$ corresponds to $D$.

2- Calculate $\iint_D xy \,dx\,dy$

I am stuck at the first question and I cannot seem to find $a, b, c$ and  $d$.

I tried to write the region $D$ such as

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
0\le x\le 1 ; \frac x2\le y\le 3x \\ 
1\le x\le 2 ; \frac x2\le y\le \frac{t-3}{s-1}(x-1)+3 \\ 
2\le x\le s ; \frac{t-1}{s-2}(x-2)+1\le y\le  \frac{t-3}{s-1}(x-1)+3 \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Then I tried to substitute with $u$ and $v$ but I was not able to find the constants.

Any hint will be very much appreciated

Comment: Hint: You'll have an easier time of it if you just consider that the function must map the vertices of E to the vertices of D.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices of $E$ are $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1).$  The suggested change of variables is $$(x,y)=F(u,v)=(au+bc+cuv, du +ev+fuv)$$  Along the edges of $E$, one of the variables $u,v$ is constant, so if we look at the coordinate functions of $F$, that is, $$F_1(u,v)=au+bc+cuv\\F_2(u,v)=du +ev+fuv$$
they are simply linear functions along the edges, because the $uv$ term will disappear.  So, it appears that $F$ will map the edges of $E$ to the edges of $D$.

We have $$\begin{align}
F(0,0)&=(0,0)\\
F(0,1)&=(bc,ev)\\
F(1,0)&=(a+bc,d+ev)\\
F(1,1)&=(a+b+c,d+e+f)
\end{align}$$

Now, let's guess that $$\begin{align}
(bc, ev)&= (2,1)\\
(a+bc,d+ev)&=(1,3)\\
(a+b+c,d+e+f)&=(s,t)
\end{align}$$

We must have $a=-1$, $d=2$, $bc=2$, $ev=1$.  The last equation gives $$s=-1+b+\frac2b\\t=2+e+\frac1e$$ and we can solve for $b$ abd $e$ in terms of $s$ and $t$.

There's no guarantee that this will work, though I'd be surprised if it doesn't.  Once you get $F$, check that it works.  If it doesn't, and you're sure it doesn't, go back and make a different guess about which vertex maps to which vertex, and see if that works.

Good luck.

Comment: I have made a mistake in the exercise I posted since x should become au + bv +cuv, however, I do not think it changes much in the method you explained.
I have just tried it and I think it worked.
Thank you very much!